# Seleccionar columnas de una tabla para usarlas después en otra consulta

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

He buscado esta pregunta en el foro pero no la encuentro. Quiero básicamente hacer una consulta que devuelva datos en común entre dos tablas, pero tengo problemas para guardar lo que quiero. Me explico mejor:

Sea la tabla 1:

```
TABLE 1

id_algo
Atributo 2
Atributo 3
```

Sea la tabla 2:

```
TABLE 2

id_algo
Atributo 4
Atributo 5
```

Como se puede observar, la tabla 1 y 2 tienen un atributo con el mismo nombre.

Mi objetivo es:

- Seleccionar de la tabla 1 los atributos: id_algo, Atributo 2
- Hacer un inner join con la tabla 2 mediante el atributo id_algo, el cual ambos comparten.
- Imprimir id_algo, Atributo 2 y Atributo 5 solamente.

¿Qué he hecho?

```
SELECT id_algo, Atributo 2 "como tabla/vista/whatever A, esto es lo que no se hacer"
FROM TABLE 1
INNER JOIN TABLE 2
ON A.id_algo = TABLE 2.id_algo
<<AQUI ME FALTA ELEGIR QUE SE IMPRIMA SOLO id_algo, Atributo 2 y Atributo 5, se hace con un GROUP BY?>>
```

Comment: Buenas Keka, si con "foro" te refieres a [es.so], esto no es un foro. En la red [se] se consideran *sitios* a cada grupo de esa red. Con "atributos" te refieres a campos?

Comment: @lois6b Gracias por la aclaración, perdona por la ignorancia. De todas formas espero  excusar mi torpeza adjuntando la definición de foro: "Un foro de Internet es un sitio de discusión online asincrónico donde las personas publican mensajes alrededor de un tema, creando de esta forma un hilo de conversación jerárquico" De ahi que pensara que esto era un foro ^^

Comment: Precisamente dices "sitio de discusión". aqui las preguntas de discusion se consideran *basadas en opiniones* y se cierran. Para ello está meta. Además aqui la jerarquia usada en un foro no se aplica. se basa en sistema de votos. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editado con los cambios sugeridos por [lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63289/seleccionar-columnas-de-una-tabla-para-usarlas-despu%C3%A9s-en-otra-consulta#comment114682_63291)

```
Select 
    id_algo,
    Atributo_2,
    Atributo_5
from 
    table_1 
inner join 
    table_2 
on 
    table_1.id_algo = table2.id_Algo:
```

Comment: No uses comentarios como "no estoy demasiado seguro", "creo"  y demás porque pierdes credibilidad. Ante dudas, considera preguntar al autor en los comentarios de su pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Entendido, gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: @Macupo con eso me ha valido gracias. Esperemos que lois no me edite este comentario porque no se pueda dar las gracias o algo que no sepa...^^

Comment: @KekaBron ay si pudiera editar comentarios ... xD espero que no te ofendieras. Las preguntas y respuestas son publicaciones objetivas y se ha hablado en Meta de [se] el quitar ese tipo de comentarios de "buenos dias", "hola que tal", "gracias" .. etc. de hecho en [so] hay scripts automaticos que lo hacen. en los comentarios, si, ya se habla un poco más subjetivamente y puedes agradecer la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Para evitar confusiones resulta muy útil usar los alias de tablas, (`from table1 T1` o `inner join table2 T2`)  de esta forma, los campos pueden llamarse con el alias: `T1.id_algo, T1.Atributo_2, T2.Atributo_5`